# Indy10 File Transfer Causes 100% CPU Usage

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, indy10

i managed to fix some errors with disconnecting, now whenever a file is transferring the CPU Usage becomes 100%, i dunno what im doing wrong :S.....

```
const
 MaxBufferSize = 1024;

type
 TClient = class(TObject)
 public
  AContext: TIdContext;
  FileSize: Integer;
  Canceled: Boolean;
  Transfered: Integer;
  procedure ReceiveData;
  procedure Update;
 end;

procedure TForm1.IdTCPServer1Execute(AContext: TIdContext);
var
 Data: string;
 Client: TClient;
 Item: TListItem;
begin
 Data := AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadLn;

 //Data := 'SEND|785548' = Command + | + FileSize
 if Copy(Data, 1, 4) = 'SEND' then
 begin
  Delete(Data, 1, 5);
  Client := TClient.Create;
  Client.FileSize := StrToInt(Data);
  Client.AContext := AContext;
  Item := ListView1.Items.Add;
  Item.Caption := AContext.Connection.Socket.Binding.PeerIP;
  Item.Data := Client;
  Client.ReceiveData;
 end;
end;

procedure TClient.ReceiveData;
var
 currRead : Integer;
 FS: TFileStream;
begin
 Canceled := False;
 FS := TFileStream.Create('C:\Test.dat', fmCreate or fmOpenReadWrite);
 FS.Size := 0;
 Transfered := 0;
 try
  while (FS.Position < FileSize) and (Athread.Connection.Connected) and (not Canceled) do
  begin
   Application.ProcessMessages;
   if (FileSize - FS.Position) >= MaxBufferSize then currRead := MaxBufferSize
   else currRead := (FileSize - FS.Position);
   AThread.Connection.IOHandler.ReadStream(FS, CurrRead);
   Transfered := FS.Position;
   Notify.NotifyMethod(Update);
   Application.ProcessMessages;
  end;
 finally
  FS.Free;
  AThread.Connection.IOHandler.InputBuffer.Clear;
  AThread.Connection.Disconnect;
  AThread.RemoveFromList;
  Notify.NotifyMethod(Update);
  Application.ProcessMessages;
 end;
end;

procedure TClient.Update;
begin
 //Code to Display Progress bar and stuff (Simplified for now)
 Form1.Label1.Caption := 'Transfered Data : ' + IntToStr(Transfered);
end;
```

Answer (score 6):

Get rid of Application.ProcessMessages; it MUST NOT be called under thread other than main one

Comment: Furthermore, get rid of the ListView1.Items.Add call; it's a VCL method, so it mustn't be called from outside the VCL thread.

Comment: same effect, now CPU Usage varies from 98% to 100%

Answer (score 4):

You're calling Application.ProcessMessages in your receive loop, presumably to keep the rest of your application from appearing to be frozen.  The 100% CPU usage is a side effect.

You're better off using an IdAntiFreeze component (still kind of a hack) or putting the ReceiveData functionality in a thread.

Update:

Whoops.  At first glance, I thought this was a client side transfer running in the main thread, but it's actually being called in a separate IdTcpServer thread.  In this case, APZ28's advice is correct; don't call Application.ProcessMessages in a thread.

Answer (score 2):

I dont' know anything about Indy (I use my own unit, which is lighter/faster than Indy, for all TCP/IP client/server stuff - see http://synopse.info), but I guess your IdTCPServer1Execute method should run in a background thread, which is not the case here.

So :

1. Get rid of all those Application.ProcessMessages and such;
2. Use a timer to synchronize your UI (a one second refresh reading the transferred byte count is enough), and not a Notify() nor Synchronize() method;
3. Ensure that your IdTCPServer1 component is running in a separate thread (there should be some property to do that);
4. Another possibility (very unlikely) is that the ReadStream method don't have to be called as such, and don't wait for data in a CPU-friendly way; if it's the case, there should be some method made available by Indy to wait for pending data, without blocking.
5. Use a profiler (there are some free one around - like http://delphitools.info ) to guess where your CPU is burnt.
6. Run outside the IDE - is it the same behavior?

Comment: i tried almost everything, except non-blocking stream read, i dont really know how to do this....., any idea on how its done? thx for answering

Comment: ok ty, but does ur components support unicode? cause thats y im moving to indy10 at the first place

Comment: Of course, SynCrtUnit works and is tested from Delphi 6 up to Delphi XE. It uses an AnsiString type, which you can easily convert to a Unicode string.

Answer (score 1):

Your looping constantly, an easy hack is to add an `Sleep(1)` after your `Application.ProcessMessages`.

But perhaps you could reorder your code to block on the ReadStream function, and only run when a reasonable amount of data is received, or a timeout has passed.

Comment: it lowered down the CPU Usage to 90%, but the transfer now is much slower, how can i do that blocking thing? and actually the Clients are Sending data in 1024 byte chunks

Comment: try to remove all the `Application.ProcessMessages`, and also the `Notify.NotifyMethod(Update);`

Comment: all Application.ProcessMessages removed, and after removing Notify there was no diffrence

Comment: that blocking thing might not be possible with Indy, if I remember correctly Indy is event based.. so you could use event handlers to handle new data, if you want a simple loop, use synopse, with the much cooler way to do tcp protocols (blocking)

Answer (score 1):

You and I covered this topic in the [Embarcadero forums](https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?threadID=46075&tstart=0) ([cached on CodeNewsFast](http://www.codenewsfast.com/cnf/article/1781753013/permalink.art-ng1921q5227)).

Comment: will u take a look at it?
http://plunder.com/80961bd7e3 sorry if it has some error, i was trying to get it to work :(

Comment: On the forums: `The specified thread [46075] was not found.` Anyone who cached it? (It's not on web.archive.org)

Comment: The Embarcadero newsgroups/forums are cached at [codenewsfast](http://www.codenewsfast.com).